# AWS DMS Migration Questions

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-dms, dms

I am new to AWS DMS and trying to understand some detail however unable to find answers so any help on this is highly appreciated.

**Q1** - If you have distributed database at your corporate data center ( on prem) , Do you need to create DMS for each of distributed database? if so does it sync all when it does CDC

**Q2** - Can DMS replicate from the standby database?

Answer (score 1):

Q1) Assuming you use a single URL to connect to the database, you should only need that single set of connection information to replicate the databases.

Q2) If you are just doing a full load and no on going replication, then yes, this is possible.  If you are talking about ongoing replication, it depends on the database but it usually requires additional logging to be enabled. For example, Oracle requires the addition of supplemental logging, and MySQL requires row-level binary logging (bin logging).  Many times standby databases don't have those enabled but, assuming they are enabled on your instance, it should be possible.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html

Comment: Thank you JD D, you have explained really well.

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Create a single DMS endpoint to the master node (or to any slave if you've  not a master) of your distributed database. It's enough for your data migration

Q2) Yes for full load migration. If you need an ongoing replication you've to enable the LogMiner or Binlogs in your data source before.